# ASP.NET MVC API Method very slow

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have an sql stored procedure that returns 926 rows and each row has 238 columns, that stored procedure takes 1 second to return. Now I am trying to run the stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC and return the results in model class called Report, see my method before, however it run this code and return the items into a class it takes forever, sometimes freezes my browser. How would I go about speeding up this process?

```
public List<KeyValuePair<object, List<Report>>> GetReportTest(string area, int? isAlphabeticalSort)
        {

            List<KeyValuePair<object, List<Report>>> ReportData = new List<KeyValuePair<object, List<Report>>>();

            try
            {
                using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetTasks", connection))
                    {
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        SqlParameter parameter1 = new SqlParameter(“@area”, SqlDbType.VarChar);
                        parameter1.Value = area;
                        parameter1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                        command.Parameters.Add(parameter1);

                        SqlParameter parameter2 = new SqlParameter("@isAlphabeticalSort", SqlDbType.Bit);
                        parameter2.Value = isAlphabeticalSort;
                        parameter2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                        command.Parameters.Add(parameter2);

                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                var model = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();

                                List<Report> report = new List<Report>();

                                for (int i = 1; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                                {
                                    RedBlue item = new RedBlue();

                                if (reader.GetName(i).ToString().Contains("Task"))
                                {
                                    item.task = reader.GetValue(i).ToString();

                                    i++;
                                }

                                if (reader.GetName(i).ToString().Contains("BID"))
                                {
                                    item.baselinefinish = reader.GetValue(i).ToString();

                                    i++;

                                }

                                if (reader.GetName(i).ToString().Contains("AID"))
                                {
                                    item.actualenddate = reader.GetValue(i).ToString();

                                    redBlue.Add(item);

                                }

                                if (reader.GetName(i).ToString().Contains("ClosingDate"))
                                {
                                    item.baselinefinish = reader.GetValue(i).ToString();

                                    redBlue.Add(item);
                                }

                                if (reader.GetName(i).ToString().Contains("DaysToClosing"))
                                {
                                    item.baselinefinish = reader.GetValue(i).ToString();

                                    redBlue.Add(item);
                                }

                                if (reader.GetName(i).ToString().Contains("ScheduleVariance"))
                                {
                                    item.baselinefinish = reader.GetValue(i).ToString();

                                    redBlue.Add(item);
                                }

                                if (reader.GetName(i).ToString().Contains("DaysOfConstruction"))
                                {
                                    item.baselinefinish = reader.GetValue(i).ToString();

                                    redBlue.Add(item);
                                }

                                if (reader.GetName(i).ToString().Contains("IDNOTES"))
                                {
                                    item.baselinefinish = reader.GetValue(i).ToString();

                                    redBlue.Add(item);
                                }

                                if (reader.GetName(i).ToString() == "PDIToClose")
                                {
                                    item.baselinefinish = reader.GetValue(i).ToString();

                                    redBlue.Add(item);
                                }
                                }

                                ReportData(new KeyValuePair<object, List<Report>>(model, report));

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return ReportData;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: your data structure doesn't look very efficient. Why do you need a new Report() object for each field in the database? Surely there's a better structure you can use. You will be instantiating 220388 (i.e. 927*238) brand new Report objects, plus 926 Key value pairs, every time you run this. I doubt that is good for performance.

Comment: Also it looks like you don't actually store anything in your Report objects, you just create empty ones and add them to your ReportData. What's the point of that, exactly?

Comment: I am storing data in my Reports object, each item gets an object, thats my main goal get key and have multiple reports for each key, ill add my code

Comment: I've updated my question with more code.

Comment: Profile your code with a performance profiler. Come back and report on the results for more help. That will give you (and us) a better idea of where your code is slow.

Comment: Did you check if you ever exits for loop? I see for loop counter is conditionally incremented.